# Excel VBA return uppercase section of string

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a function that will return an uppercase section from a longer mixed case string.

I have addresses that are entered as a string with the Suburb as uppercase and want to extract the suburb and postcode

e.g.

```
strInput = "01 Street St SUBURB 1111"
desired function output = "SUBURB 1111"
```

Please keep in mind that some suburbs are two words eg "THIS SUBURB 2222"

Here's what I have so far, but it isn't working. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Function Suburb(strInput As String) As String

Dim strTest As String
Dim strEnd As Integer
Dim n As Integer, counter As Integer

'Count the characters in the string and set variable to string length - 5 (for postcode)
strSubEnd = Len(strInput) - 5
counter = 1

'Start Loop
For n = 1 To strEnd
    'start from First Character and move to first space
    n = InStr(counter, strInput, " ")

    'create sting to test
    strTest = Mid(strInput, n + 1, strSubEnd - n)

    'check if string is upper case
    If strTest = UCase(strTest) Then
        Suburb = Mid(strInput, n + 1, Len(strInput) - n)

    'Else increase counter and re-test
    Else: counter = n
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Comment: I have came across other issues using the solution provided by Scott (below) so am trying to resolve the issues with my original code.

I think the issue is in the Loop I am using to move through the string as when I test each line between For and Next, I get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split to split the string on the spaces and test whether it is not a number and upper case:

```
Function Suburb(strInput As String) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim spltStr() As String
spltStr = Split(strInput)

For i = 0 To UBound(spltStr)
    If UCase(spltStr(i)) = spltStr(i) And Not IsNumeric(spltStr(i)) Then
        Suburb = Suburb & " " & spltStr(i)
    End If
Next i

Suburb = Trim(Suburb) & Right(strInput, 5)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott
Is there an easy way to modify this to return the street section as another function?

Comment: Just use SUBSTITUTE, substitute what is in B1 with an empty string `""`

Comment: I have used the following code to return "01 Street St" in cell C1
 

    Function Street(strInput As String, Suburb As String) As String

    Street = Replace(strInput, Suburb, "")

    End Function

Comment: Scott,
I have encountered an issue with "PO Box"; the PO picks up in the SUBURB because it is upper case.

Any suggestions?
With my original code structure was trying to work left to right, testing string sections for upper case, but could not get it to work.

Comment: Above issue resolved with:

For i = 0 To UBound(spltStr)
    If UCase(spltStr(i)) = spltStr(i) And Not IsNumeric(spltStr(i)) And Not UCase(spltStr(i)) = "PO" Then
        Suburb = Suburb & " " & spltStr(i)
    End If
Next i

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strTest As String
Dim strEnd As Integer
Dim n As Integer

'Count the characters in the string and set variable to string length - 5 (for postcode)
strEnd = Len(strInput) - 5
counter = 1

'Start Loop
For n = 1 To strEnd
'start from First Character and check if it is a space
If Mid(strInput, n, 1) = " " Then
'create sting to test
strTest = Mid(strInput, n + 1, strEnd - n)
'check if string is upper case
If strTest = UCase(strTest) Then
    Suburb2 = Mid(strInput, n + 1, Len(strInput) - n)
    Exit For
'Else move to next character and re-test
End If
End If
Next n
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### My approach with regular expression

```
Public Function Suburb(strInput As String) As String

    Dim RegExp As Object

    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegExp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "(([A-Z]+)\s)?([A-Z]+)\s([0-9]+)"
        With .Execute(strInput)
            If .Count <> 0 Then
                Suburb = .Item(0).Value
            End If
        End With
    End With
    Set RegExp = Nothing

End Function
```